# Linq не работает с AngleSharp

Tags: c#, linq, anglesharp

Почему-то при проходе циклом, все работает отлично.
Но когда я пытаюсь сделать это линку, выдает null.

Вопрос больше связан с `Linq`, чем с `AgnleSharp`.

```
List<IElements> elements = new List<IElements>();
foreach (var element in document.QuerySelector("div.composizioni").QuerySelectorAll("div"))
{
    if (element.ClassName.Contains("gallery-title font21"))
        elements.Add(element);
}
```

```
List<IElements> elements = document.QuerySelector("div.composizioni").QuerySelectorAll("div").Where(x => x.ClassName.Contains("gallery-title font21")));
```

Comment: Наверно потому, что вы пропустили в LINQ `.QuerySelectorAll("div")`?

Comment: Я удалил случайно, там был `div`

Comment: А ну да, все впорядке, у меня почему-то при .Count() крашилось, я подумал что с регуляркой проблема

Comment: В общем если я вызываю `.LastOrDefault()` или `.Count()` выдает `NullReferenceExc` а если беру `FirtsOrDefault()` выдает нужный, первый элемент. Почему не работает как надо?

Comment: Ну вы занимайтесь отладкой, смотрите что получаете, какие элементы в коллекции и так далее. Вот к примеру, что за неведомый `aboba`? Или, где в вопросе `.LastOrDefault()`, `.FirstOrDefault()`, `.Count()`? Вы ведь понимаете, что говорите про то, что нам не показываете? Также, как и не показываете HTML, с которым работаете. Единственное, что я  могу тут сказать, так это то, что `NullReference` - это означает то, что вы обратились к объекту, который `NULL`, все.

Comment: `.QuerySelectorAll("div").Where(x => x.ClassName.Contains("gallery-title font21"))` = `QuerySelectorAll("div.gallery-title.font21")`